# how to assign values to a three dimension matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I give a small example: matrix A[3*3*2], only 9 elements of matrix A are '1',other elements of A are '0'. (the value of '1' and '0' do not matter, just indicate the number of voxels, and following 5 values belong to the 9 elements of matrix A.

```
    matrix B = [ 12 
                 34 
                 61 
                 81 
                 42 ];


 matrix C = [ 1 2 1
              1 1 1
              2 3 1
              2 2 1
              3 1 1];
```

The 5 elements belong to the 9 elements of matrix A.
How to assign the values of matrix B to matrix A based on the matrix C?

Comment: It'll be really helpful if you'll provide an example of what you're trying to do (e.g. using `3x3x2` matrix `A`, `5x1` matrix `B` and `5x3` matrix `C`).

Comment: let me try to make a small example

Comment: use linear indexing via `sub2ind`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do that using  **linear indexing** via  [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
A(sub2ind(size(A),C(:,1),C(:,2),C(:,3)))=B;
```

Comment: how to change those elements (original value are '1') but without values in B to value'0'?

Comment: For change them to zero: `A(sub2ind(size(A),C(:,1),C(:,2),C(:,3)))=0;`